# C - memmove() function - How many bytes am I moving in this implementation?

Tags: c, memmove

This seems to be a great place. My question is, what value (or how many bytes) am I moving in this implementaion of memmove()?

```
int main ()
{
char str[] = "memmove can be very useful......";
memmove (str+15,str+20,/*?*/);
puts (str);
return 0;
}
```

In the next example it says I am moving 11 bytes. But what makes it 11 bytes? Could somebody explain?

```
int main ()
{
char str[] = "memmove can be very useful......";
memmove (str+20,str+15,11); //source and destination are reversed
puts (str);
return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Edit: BTW, the string length is 33 including the terminating null character.

Comment: `int main()` should be `int main(void)`.  More important, you need `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <string.h>`.  If your compiler didn't warn you about this, crank up its warning level until it does.

Comment: What you're showing us isn't an "implementation of memmove()", it's merely a program that calls `memmove()`.  An *implementation* of `memmove()` would be the code in the runtime library that actually copies the bytes.

Comment: The 11 makes it 11 bytes. Duh. In the first example you are not moving anything until you put a number in place of /*?*/. Are you confusing memmove with strcpy?

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of `memmove` specifies the number of bytes to move, so in your second example you are moving 11 bytes.  Your first example should not compile because you will have a syntax error on the line that calls `memmove`.

Answer (score 0):

The final argument to memmove() is the number of bytes to move - in this case 11

Comment: @Keith Thompson Do you know how many bytes it should be in the first example?

Comment: @Mikemmm: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Keith Thompson I am trying to left-shift elements of an array, over-writing the intial one with the one to it's right and subsequently all the elements to the right of it. Kind of like deleteing from a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Third parameter defines how many bytes to copy; in the first example you should be defining how many bytes to copy.

Comment: Incorrect.  `str+15` is the same as `&str[15]`; both expressions are of type `char*`.

Comment: I removed my downvote after the edit (though this is still redundant with other answers).